# Why are vampires at Castle Volkihar attacking me even though I'm a Vampire Lord, too?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I became a Vampire Lord, but one or two vampire NPCs still attack me in the castle and trigger all others, so I can't continue questline. Is there any fix for it?

I tried to switch off all mods and activated console command: player.setrace NordRaceVampire but still nothing happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found solution.

You must teleport to another location with console, spell or just running away from the castle, and then return back. So this problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

They are not meant to attack you on your first visit to the castle or at all if you are following the Vampire Lord questline. Turning into a vampire lord will never pacify a hostile NPC, and your choice of words leads me to believe they were hostile to you before your transformation. Your best bet is to reload to a save before aggravating them.